# How to correctly emulate terminal in linux/macOS using exex(go)?

Tags: go, terminal-emulator

I need to emulate a terminal in `go`. I try to do it like this:

```
lsCmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "ls")
lsOut, err := lsCmd.Output()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(lsOut))
```

And it seems to work correctly (the native ubuntu terminal displays a horizontal list, and the result of this function goes vertically).

But if I specifically call the wrong command, for example `exec.Command ("bash", "-c", "lss")`, I get:

> panic: exit status 127

And in the native ubuntu terminal I get the following result:

> Command 'lss' not found, did you mean:

and enumeration of commands.

I need to communicate with the native terminal, and get the same thing as the result of the command if I wrote the command in the standard ubuntu terminal.

What is the best way to do this? Maybe the `exec` library is not suitable for this? All this is necessary for front-end communication with the OS terminal. On a simple `html/css/js` page, the user enters a command, after `go` it sends it to the native terminal of the operating system and returns the result to the front-end.

How I can get the same result of executing commands as if I were working in a native terminal?

Comment: https://github.com/creack/pty#shell

Comment: The shell writes the error to stderr.  Capture stderr from the child process and print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem

> But if I specifically call the wrong command, for example exec.Command
>   ("bash", "-c", "lss"), I get:
>
> ```
> panic: exit status 127
> ```
>
> And in the native ubuntu terminal I get the following result:
>
> ```
> Command 'lss' not found, did you mean:
> ```
>
> and enumeration of commands.

This has nothing to do with Go, and the problem is actually two-fold:

- Ubuntu ships with a special package, [`command-not-found`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=command-not-found), which is usually preinstalled, which tries make terminal more friently for mere mortals by employing two techniques:

  - It tries to suggest corrections for misspellings (your case).
  - It tries to suggest packages to install when the user tries to execute a program which would have been be available if the user had a specific package installed.
- When the command is not found, "plain" (see below) shell fails the attempt by returning a non-zero exit code.
  This is absolutely expected and normal.
  I mean, panicking on it is absolutely unwise.
- There's a historical difference on how a shell is run on a Unix system.

  When a user logs into the system (remember that back in the days the concept of the shell was invented you'd be logging in via a [hardware computer terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) which was basically what your GNOME Terminal window is but in hardware, and connected over a wire),
  the so-called *login shell* is started.
  The primary idea of a logic shell is to provide *interactive* environment for the user.

  But as you surely know, shells are also capable of executing scripts.
  When a shell executes a script, it's running in a non-interactive mode.

#### The modes a Unix shell can work in

Now let's dig deeper into that thing about interactive vs non-interactive shells.

- In the interactive mode:

  - The shell is usually connected to a real terminal (either hadrware or a [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal); your GNOME Terminal window is a terminal emulator).
    "Connected" means that the shell's [standard I/O streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) are connected to the terminal, so that what the shell prints is displayed by the terminal.
  - It enables certain bells and whistles for the user, usually providind limited means for editing what is being input (`bash`, for instance, engages [GNU `readline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline/).
- In the non-interactive mode:

  - The shell's standard I/O streams are connected to some files (or to "nowhere" — like `/dev/null`).
  - No bells and whistles are enabled — as there is nobody to make use of them.

GNU `bash` is able to run in both modes, and which mode it runs in depends
on [how it was invoked](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html#Invoking-Bash).

When initializing in different modes, `bash` *reads different initialization scripts,* and this explains why the machinery provided by the `command-not-found` package gets engaged in the interactive mode and does not when bash is run otherwise — like in your invocation from Go.

#### What do do about the problem

The simplest thing to try is to run bash with the `--login` command-line option or otherwise make it think it runs as an interactive shell.

This might solve the problem for your case but not necessarily.
The next possible problem is that *some* programs do really check whether they're running at a terminal — usually these are programs which insist on real interaction with the user, usually for security purposes, and there are programs which simply cannot run when not connected to a real terminal — these are "full-screen" text UI programs such as GNU Midnight Commander, Vim, Emacs, GNU Nano and anything like this.

To solve this problem, the only solution is to run the shell in a pseudo-terminal environment, and that's what @eudore hinted at in their comment.
The [`github.com/creack/pty`](https://github.com/creack/pty) might be a package to start looking at; [`golang.org/x/crypto/ssh`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh) also provides some means to wrangle PTYs.